# Signed apk doesn't work on my device

Tags: android, apk, signed, xamarin

I've developped an android application using Xamarin. It works fine on the emulator but crashes on real device. The apk gets installed on the device and on opening the app it says "application has stopped unexpectedly.Please try again" and forces the application to close. Targeting framework, minimum sdk version etc everything is fine but still does not work. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: post your logcat error.

Comment: My android log says "E/PackageManager( 1217): Couldn't copy package file to temp file.Deployment failed because of an internal error: There is not enough storage space on the device to store package: /data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.Platform.apk. Free up some space and try again." I've more than enough internal space(28MB) and 325MB of sd card space.

Comment: My guess that 28MB is to low for Android. You could move/remove some apps to make free space, or you set in your build settings that the app must deploy to SD-CARD.

Comment: I have tried with android:installLocation="preferExternal" in my AndroidManifest but still no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you're debugging with Xamarin Studio (or Visual Studio), Xamarin.Android will install the Mono runtime and support files separately.If your application is Debug-built app, then  the problem will be that the shared runtime isn't present. So on "Release" mode please ensure that  you uncheck "Use shared mono runtime" on project options. I have attached the screenshot please go through. [image]

Comment: Thanks it working perfect, but seems apk file size bigger than previous one.

Comment: Yes because it contains supporting libraries.

Comment: Could not find this option in Visual Studio on Windows.

Comment: @UlyssesAlves right-click on your android project from solution explorer, then choose Properties. Choose Android Options from the left side of the window and there it is!.